# selenium output find_element_by_xpath into list

Tags: selenium, xpath

When using `find_element_by_xpath` it will return a str of all text inside that xpath. The output returns a str but I would need to convert this into a list. Or just return "1 bed room".

selenium xpath

```
result = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="summary"]/following-sibling::*[1]').text
```

OUTPUT

```
2 guests
1 bedroom
1 bed
1.5 baths
```

Desired output

```
[2 guests,1 bedroom,1 bed,1.5 baths]
```

Comment: Split on the newline character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting by newline should give you what you want.

```
result = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="summary"]/following-sibling::*[1]').text
result.splitlines()
```

Unless there are other elements under the element your xpath returns this is the best you can do.